# Is there a better way to return first name and second name initial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Given the name "`Rigobert Song`" How can I return "`Rigobert S.`"?

The name can be `Rigobert J. Song` or just `Rigobert`. I want to return `Rigobert S.` for the earlier and `Rigobert` for the latter.

I wrote this, which works. Is there a more "Ruby way"?

```
def initials_for(user)
  if user.name.split.size > 1
    "#{user.name.split.first} #{user.name.split.last[0]}"
  else
    user.name
  end
end
```

Comment: Your code does not give what you wrote you are looking for. Hint: period.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I thought I was using the `split` function too many times. It felt a bit wrong.

Comment: Check out [CodeReview SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: You might want to have a look at [_Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names_](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) (it might not apply to what you’re doing at the moment, but is worth thinking about).

Comment: +1 @matt. The test case is too limited to be useful. People's names are too varied to be tested using one sample, so this question, and all answers based on it, are destined to fail big time when they hit the real world. The OP, and answerers need to consider the implications in "[Personal names around the world](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-personal-names)"

Comment: I'd recommend looking through http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_most_popular_given_names and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_most_common_surnames. Also consider how to handle a person's name that consists of a single word or contains only graphic symbols, such as "Liberace" or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Prince_logo.svg

Answer (score 4):

```
"Rigobert J. Song"
.gsub(/\s+.+\s+/, " ").sub(/(?<=\s\S).+/, ".")
# => "Rigobert S."

"Rigobert Song"
.gsub(/\s+.+\s+/, " ").sub(/(?<=\s\S).+/, ".")
 # => "Rigobert S."

"Rigobert"
.gsub(/\s+.+\s+/, " ").sub(/(?<=\s\S).+/, ".")
 # => "Rigobert"
```

Comment: That's pretty, cool, thanks, although a lot less readable for me since I'm not very good at RegEx.

Comment: @screenmutt Each part has semantic significance. The `gsub` removes intermediate name parts, and the `sub` replaces any remaining name part with its initial.

Comment: @sawa I can see it a little better. I feel like the look ahead may be a little opaque. And shouldn't it be `/(?<=\s\w).+/, ".")`?

Comment: I added an option without a lookahead. I think that may be a bit clearer.

Comment: @screenmutt Your proposed edit is redundant. You don't need the `$` anchor.

Comment: I updated it and modified the original code to support single character last names. This would be the case when an initial was provided, but not a period.

Comment: @screenmutt I think that a period in initials stands for something omitted. A single lettered name should not have a period attached.

Comment: @sawa I would assume that it was an initial that someone typed in instead of entering their whole last name. Which is kind of more likely. I can't think of any single character names.

Comment: @screenmutt If the user typed an initial without a period, then that is a mistake. If the user typed a single name (without a period), then that is correct. You should not sacrifice cases of the latter for the sake of repairing mistakes of the former. Not turning a correct input wrong is more important than turning a wrong input correct. Your assumption of ignoring single character names may have cultural bias. I also cannot come up such name, but I would not assume that there is not any.

Comment: @sawa [Good call](http://www.idogenealogy.net/2013/02/19/initials-in-names/). But aren't we asking for the initial of the last name, regardless of length.

Answer (score 2):

You dont have to split multiple times. You can take it into a variable

```
def initials_for(user)
  name_arry = user.name.split
  name_arry.size > 1 ? "#{name_arry.first} #{name_arry.last[0]}" : user.name
end
```

Comment: Missing `Hint` from @sawa.

Answer (score 1):

This would work too. But I don't know if it is necessarily a "better" solution.

```
def initials_for(user)
  parts = user.name.split
  name = parts.first
  name += " #{parts.last[0]}." if parts.length > 1
  name
end
```

Comment: I would not work if parts.length is not > 1, it will return false instead of the name, you have to add name at the end

Comment: Thanks, I forgot the last line.

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged it as ruby-on-rails, I'm assuming you have `present?` available...

```
def initials_for(full_name)
  (first_name, *, last_name) = full_name.split
  [first_name, name_initial(last_name)].reject(&:blank?).join(" ")
end

def name_initial(name)
  if name.present?
    "#{name[0]}."
  else
    ""
  end
end

puts initials_for(user.name)
```

First, I factored out the use of user inside this helper, that's a dependency that this function does not need to know about.  Pass the string in as indicated in the puts line.

I made a helper to handle the second initial with a period as several others indicate.. and then gather the parts into an array, reject the blank parts, and join them with a space.

Note the use of a splat and intention revealing variables on the left hand side of the split.   If you try it, you should see that first_name always has the leftmost name and last_name always has the rightmost name, or nil if there is only one name present.

I use this pattern of reject and join a lot, when dealing with variations of first, last, middle, maiden, and common names, leaving a readable name without extra characters and such.

Comment: Of course, this fails on "John Doe II".   But that wasn't in your specs. :D

Answer (score -1):

*edited* to correctly handle asker's example strings

I like using regex. This allows any characters in first and/or last name. There must be at most two spaces in the string.

If there are zero spaces, all characters are placed in capture group 1 as the first name.

If there is one space, the characters before the space are placed in capture group 1 as the first name and the characters after the space are placed in capture group 3 as the last name.

If there are two spaces, the characters before the first space are placed in capture group 1; the characters between the spaces in capture group 2; and the characters after the second space in capture group 3.

```
#output
Testing Rigobert Song
Rigobert S.
Testing Rigobert J. Song
Rigobert S.
Testing Rigobert J.Song
Rigobert J.
Testing RigobertJ.Song
RigobertJ.Song
Testing Rigobert
Rigobert


tests = [ "Rigobert Song", "Rigobert J. Song", "Rigobert J.Song", "RigobertJ.Song", "Rigobert", ]
regex=\
 /^([^ ]*) ?([^ ]* )?([^ ]+)?$/
#- - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
# ^- - - - - - - - - - - - - - Match start of string here
#  ^ - - ^ - - - - - - - - - - Begin/End capture group 1
#   ^^^^^- - - - - - - - - - - Match 0 or more of any non-space character
#         ^^ - - - - - - - - - Match zero or one literal space
#           ^- - - ^ - - - - - Begin/End capture group 2
#            ^^^^^ - - - - - - Match 0 or more non-space characters...
#                 ^- - - - - - ... with exactly one trailing space
#                   ^- - - - Make Capture group 2 optional (match 0 or 1)
#                    ^ - - ^ - Begin/end capture group 3
#                     ^^^^^- - Match 1 or more non-space characters
#                           ^- Make capture group 3 optional
#                            ^ Match end of string here

tests.each do |str|
  puts "Testing #{str}"
  match = regex.match(str)
  if(match != nil)
    first = match[1]
    middle = match[2] || ""
    last = match[3] || ""
    if(first != "" && last != "")
      puts(first+" "+last[0].chr+".") # ruby 1.8
      #puts(first+' '+last[0]+".")     # ruby 1.9
    else
      if(first != "" && last == "")
        puts(first)
      else
        puts('Invalid name format')
      end
    end
  else 
    puts('No regex match')
  end
end
```